# grouped barplot from table

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

After some search about my topic without a satisfing answer or one I can adapt to my data, here one more question about plotting a grouped (or stacked) barplot with either ggplot2 or barplot.

I have the following table:

```
Table_lakes
    Lake Size Lake Mean Lake Med  Lake Max  Lake Min
 1:   2419723  6.557441 6.562879  9.107328 4.7520108
 2:    737345  1.569643 1.562833  2.643082 0.9065250
 3:   1904419  3.006871 2.989362  4.100533 2.3644874
 4:    633220  3.170494 3.154871  4.580919 1.6915103
 5:   3417157  4.587906 4.589763  5.865326 3.5397623
 6:   3046643  1.784759 1.783092  2.921241 0.6835220
 7:   3868608  2.152185 2.188566  5.382725 0.1158626
 8:  11952064  9.391443 9.342757 12.524334 8.5829620
 9:   2431961  7.796330 7.833883  9.186878 5.9242287
10:   5624563  8.444996 8.482042 12.207799 7.3909297
11:   2430490  3.474408 3.438787  5.186004 2.3032870
```

I would like to creat a grouped barplot for each ID (1-11) with the values of the mean, med, max and min. The Lake size is kind of irrelevant here.

So far I tried to help myself with this: https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/r-11-bar-charts/ and [Grouped barplot in ggplot2 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996960/grouped-barplot-in-ggplot2-in-r?rq=1)

One of my tries was this:

```
 ggplot(Table_lakes[Table_lakes$`Lake Mean` & Table_lakes$`Lake Max`],
       aes(x = factor(Name), y = Table_lakes)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="dodge") +
  labs(x = "Name", y = "Height")
```

The y axis should show the vales (about 0 to 15), the x axis the grouped Min, max, med, mean for Lakes 1 to 11 each.

Would be great if someone can provide some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using R basic plotting functions:

1/ from the data of your example:

```
    RAWDATA = "ID    Lake_Size Lake_Mean Lake_Med  Lake_Max  Lake_Min
 1:   2419723  6.557441 6.562879  9.107328 4.7520108
 2:    737345  1.569643 1.562833  2.643082 0.9065250
 3:   1904419  3.006871 2.989362  4.100533 2.3644874
 4:    633220  3.170494 3.154871  4.580919 1.6915103
 5:   3417157  4.587906 4.589763  5.865326 3.5397623
 6:   3046643  1.784759 1.783092  2.921241 0.6835220
 7:   3868608  2.152185 2.188566  5.382725 0.1158626
 8:  11952064  9.391443 9.342757 12.524334 8.5829620
 9:   2431961  7.796330 7.833883  9.186878 5.9242287
10:   5624563  8.444996 8.482042 12.207799 7.3909297
11:   2430490  3.474408 3.438787  5.186004 2.3032870"

DATA = read.table(textConnection(RAWDATA), header=TRUE)
```

2/ select the columns you want and (re)set column and row names

```
A  = DATA[, 3:6]
rownames(A) = paste0("#", 1:nrow(A))
colnames(A) = c("Mean", "Median", "Max", "Min")
```

3/ then, plot the data:

```
cols = c("blue", "darkblue",  "red", "green") # bar colors
mainsep = 0.1 # space between grouped bars
secsep = 0 # space between bars

# defining an empty plot with the right dimensions
xlim = c(0, nrow(A)-mainsep)
ylim = c(0, max(A))
plot(NA, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, xaxt="n", ylab="Lake level [m]", xlab="Lakes ID")
# create the x-axis with the table row names as labels
axis(1, at=1:nrow(A)-0.5-mainsep/2, labels=rownames(A), tick=FALSE, mgp=c(3, 0.1, 0))
axis(1, at=0:nrow(A)-mainsep/2, labels=NA, tick=TRUE)
# create the grouped bar according to the column of the table
boxsize = (1-mainsep)/ncol(A)
for (i in 1:nrow(A)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(A)) {
        rect((i-1)+boxsize*(j-1), 0, (i-1)+boxsize*j-secsep, A[i, j], col=cols[j])
    }
}
# add a legend to identify the content of each column
legend("top",  horiz=TRUE, legend=colnames(A), col="black", pt.bg=cols, pch=22, pt.cex=2)
```

This can be easily customized to your needs. Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually, from the link you provided ([https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/r-11-bar-charts/](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/r-11-bar-charts/)), you'll find a much simpler solution using barplot():

`barplot(as.matrix(t(A)), main="", ylab="Lake level [m]", beside=TRUE, col=cols)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually I just get an empty plot, when I use the same script with, of course, changing it accordingly to my data. Don't know whats the problem.

Comment: I also tried it once more with the link you copied in your comment. There I always get the wrong groups (max, min,..) instead of groups of the same id. So I tried to help out by transposing the table according to the id, but it still plots for the max, min,...groups and not for every id. Do you might know why?

Comment: I don’t know why transposing the table doesn’t work. It should. Is you table a data.frame, a matrix? With you table named “Table_lakes”, The following should work: `barplot(t(as.matrix(Table_lakes[, c("Lake_Mean", "Lake_Med", "Lake_Max", "Lake_Min")])), main="", ylab="Lake level [m]", beside=TRUE, col=c("lightblue", "darkblue",  "red", "green"))`Note that the rownames of Table_lakes are taken as labels of the groups on the x axis.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ivan! Your new comment works perfectly! =)

Answer (score 0):

Put the data into a csv file named "test.csv" like this:

```
    id  size    mean    med max min
1   2419723 6.557441    6.562879    9.107328    4.7520108
2   737345  1.569643    1.562833    2.643082    0.906525
3   1904419 3.006871    2.989362    4.100533    2.3644874
4   633220  3.170494    3.154871    4.580919    1.6915103
5   3417157 4.587906    4.589763    5.865326    3.5397623
6   3046643 1.784759    1.783092    2.921241    0.683522
7   3868608 2.152185    2.188566    5.382725    0.1158626
8   11952064    9.391443    9.342757    12.524334   8.582962
9   2431961 7.79633 7.833883    9.186878    5.9242287
10  5624563 8.444996    8.482042    12.207799   7.3909297
11  2430490 3.474408    3.438787    5.186004    2.303287
```

Then write the code below:

```
require(reshape2)
#the reshape2 package is required here
testData <- read.csv('~/Desktop/test.csv')
testData$id <- as.factor(testData$id) 
#convert the id field to factors instead of numerical values
testDataMelt <- reshape2::melt(testData, id.vars = "id", value.name = "value")
testDataMelt <- testDataMelt[testDataMelt$variable != "size",]
#convert the data to the format that is convenient for plotting by ggplot2 and remove the size field
ggplot(testDataMelt, aes(x = id, y = value, group = variable, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
#finally, ggplot the data
```

The plot:

[image: plot.jpg]

Hope this helps!