# Grouped barplots in R using csv

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a 3 column csv file like this

```
x,y1,y2
100,50,10
200,10,20
300,15,5
```

I want to have a barplot using R, with first column values on x axis and second and third columns values as grouped bars for the corresponding x. I hope I made it clear. Can someone please help me with this? My data is huge so I have to import the csv file and can't enter all the data.I found relevant posts but none was exactly addressing this.
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grouped barplot in ggplot2 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996960/grouped-barplot-in-ggplot2-in-r)

Comment: What I understand is no it doesn't. The structure of data is different.

Comment: See my answer, does it helps you out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% pivot_longer(names_to = "y", values_to = "value", -x) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,value, fill=y))+geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]
**Data**

```
df = structure(list(x = c(100L, 200L, 300L), y1 = c(50L, 10L, 15L), 
    y2 = c(10L, 20L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Hi, Thankyou for responding. I don't have so much expertise in R. My data is huge so I want to import it using read.csv function as it is not possible to enter all the data. Can I work with the solution you provided by using csv file?

Comment: Yes, use `df = read.csv("Name_of_file.csv")`. Then run the code provided by me.

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you. But it seems to plot wrong values at some points. Also want to ask if we can change the colors here and size and orientation of x-axis labels? I am familiar with these options of barplot function. Do you know the solution to my posted question, by using just barplot function and not any other package? Googling didn't help me finding it out.